# 401 Unauthorised when processing a Clerk Webhook in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webhooks, next.js13, clerk

when i sync clerk data to my back end using webhook and do all steps i recive 401 error on vercel Log

this is app/api/webhook/route.ts

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createUser, updateUser, deleteUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  // TODO: add your webhook secret to .env.loca
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt: WebhookEvent;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    }) as WebhookEvent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the event type
  const eventType = evt.type;

  console.log({ eventType });

  // Handle the event
  if (eventType === "user.created") {
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;

    // Create a new user in your database
    const mongoUser = await createUser({
      clerkId: id,
      name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
      username: username!,
      email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
      picture: image_url,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.updated") {
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;

    // Update a user in database
    const mongoUser = await updateUser({
      clerkId: id,
      updateData: {
        name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
        username: username!,
        email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
        picture: image_url,
      },
      path: `/profile/${id}`,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
    const { id } = evt.data;

    // Delete a user in database
    const deletedUser = await deleteUser({ clerkId: id! });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
  }

  return new Response("", { status: 200 });
}
```

middleware.ts

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: [
    "/",
    "/api/webhook",
    "question/:id",
    "/tags",
    "/tags/:id",
    "/profile/:id",
    "/community",
    "/jops",
  ],
  ignoredRoutes: ["/api/webhook", "/api/chatgpt"],
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

after deploy my app in vercel and copy url on clerk endpoint then clerk faild and i get 401 [post] api/webhook

what shoud i do to solve this 401 warnning

i try to change ignoredRoutes once i add it and delete it, once change webhooksecret in .envlocal and add env variables on vercel and re-deploy and nothing change

Answer (score 1):

In your project settings -> under deployment protection turn of vercel authentication.(don't forget to redeploy)
or you can push your branch to production via pushing your code to main branch
that production link will also help

Comment: I try that and I get 200 post to api/webhook then get 504 error gateway timeout -> Task timed out after 10.02 seconds all that on vercel log!!! and webhook failed

Comment: Try using localtunnel to check if your webhook is working fine

Comment: what is localtunnel ?

Comment: Read this blog to get started https://clerk.com/blog/webhooks-getting-started

Comment: this solution worked for me. i'm using Next 14.x + Clerk + Vercel

Answer (score 0):

@Ziad-Al
hace 2 semanas
​ @Jediknightcode  I solved it by going to clerk dashboard, user&authentication, email,phone, username then I clicked on the setting icon beside Username and allowed the username required, then I did the same for the Personal information I allowed the first name and last name to be required, I guess by doing this the setting in clerk dashboard is aligned with the user model we created where these info are required for the user object to be created inside the database collection

Comment: nothing changes still get 401 unauthorized

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).