# 504 Gateway Timeout when try to POST request to api route in NEXT.JS application deployed on VERCEL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

when try to post a request to api/webhooks I get 504 error gateway timeout and on vercel log I get Task timed out after 10.02 seconds

this code is a webhook between my clerk and my MongoDB

[POST] [middleware: "middleware"] /api/webhooks status=200
then get
[POST] /api/webhooks status=504

api/webhooks/route.ts

```
 /* eslint-disable camelcase */
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createUser, updateUser, deleteUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
  );
}

// Get the headers
const headerPayload = headers();
const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

// If there are no headers, error out
if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
  return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
    status: 400,
  });
}

// Get the body
const payload = await req.json();
const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

// Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

let evt: WebhookEvent;

// Verify the payload with the headers
try {
  evt = wh.verify(body, {
    "svix-id": svix_id,
    "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
    "svix-signature": svix_signature,
  }) as WebhookEvent;
} catch (err) {
  console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
  return new Response("Error occured", {
    status: 400,
  });
}

// Get the event type
const eventType = evt.type;

console.log({ eventType });

// Handle the event
if (eventType === "user.created") {
  const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
    evt.data;

  // Create a new user in your database
  const mongoUser = await createUser({
    clerkId: id,
    name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
    username: username!,
    email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
    picture: image_url,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
}

if (eventType === "user.updated") {
  const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
    evt.data;

  // Update a user in database
  const mongoUser = await updateUser({
    clerkId: id,
    updateData: {
      name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
      username: username!,
      email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
      picture: image_url,
    },
    path: `/profile/${id}`,
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
}

if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
  const { id } = evt.data;

  // Delete a user in database
  const deletedUser = await deleteUser({ clerkId: id! });

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
}

return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK" });
}
```

middleware.ts

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
publicRoutes: [
  "/",
  "/api/webhooks(.*)",
  "question/:id",
  "/tags",
  "/tags/:id",
  "/profile/:id",
  "/community",
  "/jops",
],
ignoredRoutes: ["/api/webhooks"],
});

export const config = {
matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

[photo_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQxkf.png)  [photo_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXJW8.png)[photo_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gHdu.png)[photo_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5tGo.png)
what should I do on Vercel or on my code?
before I had a 401 unauthorized but when turn of vercel authorization its gone and 504 get

Comment: Something takes way too long. Do you know which part it is? Is it only on Vercel or also locally? Might be Svix or DB that are behind firewall or are slow to respond. Add some logging to check out which one.

Comment: i eddit and add three photo from vercel log 

before that I get 401 unauth on vercel log problem here you can attend here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768548/401-unauthorised-when-processing-a-clerk-webhook-in-next-js

Comment: on  vercel log made 2 requests at the same time to the same api  URL  api/webhooks

Comment: So it looks like you get the eventType in the log so it seems to be the `updateUser` action that times out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I forgot to add access from anywhere in MongoDB  hope that's the case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).